# CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled vs CMSClassUnloadingEnabled

Tags: java, jvm-arguments

I've kind of asked this question before - [What does JVM flag CMSClassUnloadingEnabled actually do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334911/what-does-jvm-flag-cmsclassunloadingenabled-actually-do), but this time it's slightly different!

If I start a Java VM with the `-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled` flag set, the following message is printed:

> Please use CMSClassUnloadingEnabled in place of CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled in the future

The `-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled` flag is often used to mitigate against `PermGen OutOfMemory` errors, however I have [read elsewhere](http://www.coderanch.com/t/461502/Performance/java/CMSClassUnloadingEnabled-vs-CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled#2060063) that people have found that by following the above advice they have still had these errors, but by sticking with `-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled` as well as `-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled` their VM has stayed up longer between restarts.

Does `-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled` really supersede `-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled` or is there still some benefit in having them both?

Rich
ps: I know that the root cause of perm gen issues is still usually Classloader leaks, this is more about the message that the JVM produces if we use the above options.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

From what I can tell, the only thing that the 1.6 JVM does with `CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled` is to print that message - it's not processed the way it is in 1.5. For `CMSClassUnloadingEnabled` to have any impact, `UseConcMarkSweepGC` must also be set.

Comment: Thanks - do you have any links or other ways to back this up?

Comment: Download the JDK source code (which includes hotspot) and inspect `hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/globals.hpp`. `CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled` is present in 1.5 and absent in 1.6. In addition, the 1.6 version of `hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/arguments.cpp` contains new code for printing the message.

Comment: Ok looking to the jdk 1.6.23 source code didn't find any place of usage except globals.hpp where it is just set to false. So it is really used??? Sorry if i missed the place where it is used.

Comment: -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled and -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled are unusable in java 1.7, see [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html#BehavioralOptions)

Comment: According to Oracle (see https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/entry/about_g1_garbage_collector_permanent) option `-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled` is still valid for Java 1.7.

Comment: no longer valid for 1.8  - https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/about-g1-garbage-collector,-permanent-generation-and-metaspace