# PermGen errors in Jenkins

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu, jenkins

I had cases of Jenkins failures and nothing but Jenkins redeployment (Jenkins is a webapp in Tomcat) helped. Even new jobs failed with PermGen space errors, but all the settings were fine (all these `-XX:PermSize` parameters everywhere it's possible). The point is after redeployment everything worked like a charm. But it's a harsh solution. I wanted to know, if there are some options to rollback Jenkins state. Thanks in advance.

**Update**: Okay, for those, who may face something like that, here is what I figured out. Those, who wrote that it's better to deploy Jenkins as a Tomcat module probably didn't face the problems of any kind of project deployment (with Jenkins Deploy plugin or with a `tomcat-maven-plugin` in Maven's `pom.xml`). I didn't have any of the problems I described when installed Jenkins separately. Whew!

Comment: are you running under ubuntu? if yes, you need to override /etc/default/tomcat settings. Otherwise you could try to run tomcat with Jrockit JVM that does not suffer from permgenspace issues.

Comment: @jocelyn Yep, it's Ubuntu, and I tried to override those settings. Jrockit may be a solution, still it's a bit strange to change JVM because of Jenkins.

Answer (score 34):

The one setting that really matters for PermGen space errors is (and it must be this *exactly*):

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

**One** dash, **two** Big Xs, Big-M, Big-P, Big-S, no-spaces, size-in-megs, **lower case** m.  If you screw it up it will be ignored.  99% of all the PermGen fixes I see that "don't work" are because someone didn't follow instructions precisely and used a Big-M for megabytes instead of a little-m, or put two dashes in front instead of one for example.

Also, 512 megs is just a starting point... adjust to fit your system.

Comment: "**One** dash, **two** Big Xs, Big-M, Big-P, Big-S, no-spaces, size-in-megs" made me lol, nice!

Answer (score 6):

I once experienced similar errors: jenkins was executing maven builds, which included surefire tests execution. I discovered that the version of maven I was using (V2 something) did not pass my JVM memory options to the surefire process fork, and some tests were failing because of this. MAVEN_OPTS, JAVA_OPTS, none did work.

I ended up passing my memory options directly in the settings.xml, and the PermGen errors were gone.

Here are the options I used (the app was fairly big):

-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m

Comment: Thanks, maybe I'll need that, but in my case PermGen always appeared at the very beginning, not while performing tests or something else.

Answer (score 4):

Completely untested suggestion, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/88262/274466) suggests using `-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled` when starting Tomcat (albeit for an issue in a completely different context). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3720052/274466), however, suggests that `CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled` is unnecessary on Java 6 and that `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` must be used for `CMSClassUnloadingEnabled` to be effective.

At the very least `-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled` may do the trick assuming that the underlying issue is caused by classes being unnecessarily maintained in the PermGen space for your Tomcat instance.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this question can help you:

[How to give Jenkins more heap space when it´s started as a service under Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936519/how-to-give-jenkins-more-heap-space-when-its-started-as-a-service-under-windows)

There are some very good answers there.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried to enlarge all these memory parameters, it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I found bumping the `JRE` to `Java 8` helped. By default Jenkins uses the `JRE` under the home folder, invoked by the `jenkins.xml` task

Answer (score 0):

I resolved `PermGen` error in Linux by adding to `jenkins.conf`:

```
wrapper.java.additional.4=-XX:PermSize=1024M
```