# Sonar java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Tags: java, sonarqube, heap-memory, bamboo, permgen

I'm getting the following error when running a build in ant

```
buildcallbacks.xml:39: org.sonar.runner.RunnerException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

It's the part of the build where sonar runs over our code.

Is there a way for me to know exactly where this error is coming from i.e is it the sonar server or the client etc ?

Here is line 39 of my buildcallbanks.xml

```
<sonar:sonar />
```

EDIT: I've tried increasing the permsize from the wrapper.conf within Sonar and I still get the same issue no matter how high I set it. I must still be missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I actually went back to look at this after you - it was still failing.
You were nearly there but I found two things:

1. You had used JAVA_OPTS instead of ANT_OPTS
2. CMSClassUnloadingEnabled is only used if you also use UseConcMarkSweepGC. See here: [CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled vs CMSClassUnloadingEnabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717937/cmspermgensweepingenabled-vs-cmsclassunloadingenabled/3720052#3720052)

So the settings that seem to be working a treat now are:

```
ANT_OPTS="-Xmx1024m -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```

**UPDATE:**
Years later I have actually re-visited this again as the problem reoccurred. You don't actually need to mess with the GC settings, just the memory. The correct options to use are in fact:

```
ANT_OPTS="-Xmx2G -XX:MaxPermSize=1G"
```

Obviously you can tweak the memory values to suit your machine.

Hope this helps others.

Comment: Good effort on the research!

Answer (score 1):

This error is not caused by any specific line of code, so there would be no point in trying to locate it. You'll just have to reconfigure the Java runtime that ant uses so that the limit on the PermGen space is increased. [This wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/ant/TheElementsOfAntStyle) documents how to achieve this. Basically, you set the `ANT_OPTS` environment variable.

Comment: I'm setting 2048M using set ANT_OPTS=-Xmx2048M on the ant task in bamboo and I'm still getting the same issue. I'm surprised that it would need more than that?

Comment: You are using the wrong option, which controls the regular heap size. You need to set the limit for the Permanent Generation. Googling for the description of your error will give you many results with different approaches you can try.

Comment: To be fair, everything that comes up in google does leave you guessing e.g. can I set the perm size from the ant job in Bamboo? Do I set it on the sonar server itself or maybe just the client? I'm reading through the docs now. I'll post back if I find what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes, if the task in question starts its own instance of JVM, then `ANT_OPTS` will not help. You'll need some sonar-task-specific way to do it.

Comment: I've tried increasing the permsize from the wrapper.conf within Sonar and I still get the same issue not matter how high I set it. I must still be missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of increasing the heap size, try increasing the permgen size. You can do this with

```
ANT_OPTS=-XX:MaxPermSize=128m
```

The default size is 64 MB, so this setting should double the maximum memory available.

The PermGen memory is used for things that don't change often while running the JVM, like class definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the permspace on the sonar server didn't seem to have any effect.

This issue seems to have been caused by running too many ant targets at the 'assembly' stage in Bamboo. I am now running 'clean all production' followed by a call to the ant sonar plugin .jar.

It also seems that classes weren't being unloaded when they should have been. This was fixed with the following JVM parameter: -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled