# Tomcat6 crashes unexpectedly

Tags: tomcat6

I deployed web application in tomcat6,but tomcat shutdown unexpectedly.In **catalina.out** i found this line

**Please use CMSClassUnloadingEnabled in place of CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled in the future**

Any help to resolve this issue?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717937/cmspermgensweepingenabled-vs-cmsclassunloadingenabled

Comment: I already done this,I Created one new file under /bin of tomcat
named as "setenv.sh"
added  this lines inside **export JAVA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms512m -Xmx8192m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"**,But still im getting issue

Comment: @SpazzMarticus,my java version is "1.6.0_32"